# Workflow question: copy existing PrestaShop 1.7 to localhost and work on styles and js scripts

Tags: css, database, ftp, prestashop, development-environment

I have an existing Prestashop 1.7 that work on a www hosting. I want to copy it (the best with database) to my localhost for fast reloading after changes (style, js) - without sending it on ftp and refreshing domain.

I tried to use xampp, but ineffectively.

After copy all the files from public_html to `C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx` and run `xampp` i have 500 error:

```
URL: http://localhost/xxx/
Method: GET
Remote adress: 127.0.0.1:80
Error: 500
```

Comment: Hi @MSal and welcome to SO! Please make sure to check your Xamp Apache error log to see which PHP error triggered the 500 error. It might be related to your PHP version, wrong MySQL credentials or something else.

Comment: Just enable the DEBUG MODE from config/define.inc.php file so you can have a readable error instead of 500. Also make sure you have changed the database details in the app/config/parameters.php That can be the first reason of 500 error.